# Evento GridView.Sorting, duvida?

Tags: c#, gridview

Tenho o seguinte cenário no qual tenho um GridView porém quando quero ordenar descrescente ele não esta ordenando.

segue abaixo:

```
    protected void gvdNomeClientes_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.SortExpression)
            {
                case "nome":
                    if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataSource = lista.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         gvdNomeClientes.DataSource = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.nome).ToList();
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataBind();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

segue o grid:

```
        <asp:GridView runat="server" 
                ID="gvdClientes" 
                AllowPaging="true" 
                EmptyDataText="Nenhum registro foi inserido..."
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                OnRowCommand="gvdClientes_RowCommand"
                AllowSorting="true"
                OnSorting="gvdClientes_Sorting">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="nome" DataField="_nomeCliente" HeaderText="Nome" HtmlEncode="False" FooterText="">
                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField SortExpression="cidade" DataField="_cidade" HeaderText="Cidade" HtmlEncode="False" FooterText="">
                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"/>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Você não acha que "não funciona" é algo um pouco genérico demais para descrever algo que ajude as pessoas ajudar você? Coloque mais detalhes do que isto significa, o que ocorre, qual sua expectativa, o que já tentou alternativamente.

Comment: valeu pela sinalização, escrevi rápido rs, o que ocorre é o seguinte ele ordena de forma crescente, porem o decrescente não ta funcionando. não tentei fazer isso de outra maneira...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom respondendo a mim mesmo rs.. cheguei a uma solução pra esse problema, espero que ajude outras pessoas que se depararem com a mesma situação:

```
 protected void gvdNomeClientes_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 {
        if (ViewState["sortColumn"].ToString() == e.SortExpression.ToString())
            {
                if ("ASC" == ViewState["sortDirection"].ToString())
                {
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = "DESC";
                    carregaNomeClientes(ListarClientes().OrderByDescending(x => x.nome).ToList());
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
                    carregaNomeClientes(ListarClientes().OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["sortColumn"] = e.SortExpression.ToString();
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = "ASC";
                carregaNomeClientes(ListarClientes().OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList());
            }

 }
```

inicialmente declarei tambem no Page_Load da pagina:

```
            ViewState["sortColumn"] = String.Empty;
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reparei que quando é para ordenar decrescente, você faz retorna a lista para outro gridview, creio que o correto é adicionar a lista no gridview **gvdNomeClientes**

O Código abaixo deve funcionar.

```
 protected void gvdNomeClientes_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.SortExpression)
            {
                case "nome":
                    if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataSource = lista.OrderBy(x => x.nome).ToList();
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataSource = lista.OrderByDescending(x => x.nome).ToList();
                        gvdNomeClientes.DataBind();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ainda assim não funcionou. :(

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "não funcionou"?

Comment: ele não esta ordenando de forma decrescente, de forma crescente ele funciona..

Comment: Bem, com base no que está no código o único modo de não ordenar decrescente é se ele não entrar no "else". poderia colocar um break point e me dizer o que acontece?

Comment: ele nunca chega no else, toda vez que eu clico ele sempre vai no (SortDirection.Ascending)

Comment: Certo, aonde você clica p/ chamar esse evento?

Comment: eu clico no nome da coluna que está assim: na tag <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="nome">

Comment: Poderia colocar uma imagem por favor?

Comment: Paulo editei a pergunta e coloquei o codigo do grid, no caso eu clico na coluna "Nome"

Comment: resolvi Paulo, observe acima a solução, o que estava ocorrendo é que ele nunca chegava ao else, ou seja ele nao sabia dizer qual seria o estado do sorting se era crescente ou decrescente.